# Strange router's firewall behavior on Linux

Tags: windows, linux, firewall, minecraft

I have router, static ip and when I start Minecraft server on Windows, anyone can connect to it, but when I start server on Linux, only players from my local network can connect. And other players can connect when I disable firewall on router. I don't understand why I got this router's behavior on Linux. What to do with this? Did anyone had this problem?

*Update.*
My router is TL-WR740N

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Windows and Linux as dual boot on the same PC? In such case everything should work fine as you would have the same IP address assigned to Windows and Linux. If you have two separate PCs than each time you change the computer on which you start the server you need to adjust the port forwarding rule on your router to point to correct IP address.

Main Questions:

1. Are your Windows and Linux machines physically separate?
2. Do you have a dualboot on a single machine to switch between the operating systems?
3. Do you have a port forwarding rule on your router for particular port-to-ip address?

Comment: Yes, I have dual boot on same PC and in each OS I have the same IP address. And, I have port forwarding on router.

Comment: tell your friend to give you his public ip address. lets say its 90.10.10.10. Boot up your Linux and start terminal. Type in `tcpdump src 90.10.10.10` and ask your friend to try to connect to your server. Let us know if some connection have shown in the terminal window. If no then the problem is on your router. If yes then maybe Minecraft server on Linux is listening on different port then on Windows...

Comment: After I did this I got `tcpdump: no suitable device found`. And Minecraft listen the same port 25565.

Comment: you do not have a network card installed in linux or it was not recognized or the interface is down. try ifconfig eth0 up